# What were the 'compelling use' cases for YouTube and GIF support in SE?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to see if there were any obvious show-stopper issues with WebGL support in SE sites *before* opening up a likely heated debate on the question of 'should SE support WebGL'.

[The question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281165/303080) was met with some disapproval, and recommendations that I should be asking the 'should' question first.

It was suggested that I should be supplying a '[compelling use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281165/#comment913328_281165)' case first.

Since my question mentions SE's support of animated GIFs and YouTube videos, I'd like to know, or even see, the 'compelling use' GIF and video that were actually used to begin those discussions.

Comment: FWIW, GIF support is basically the same as regular image support. Both are done using a regular HTML image tag.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I didn't know if there were any subtleties involving bandwidth or imgur. Since (at least my) GIFs are sometimes blocked when they hit the 2MB upload limit when using the SE editor's upload image button, I wondered if there might have been some subtle decision making somewhere. I know imgur sometimes converts gifs to more movie-clip-like objects that I can't seem to embed here.

Comment: Cat videos and gifs, obviously.

Comment: @Won't that's what [I thought also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281165/#comment913331_281165). But that discussion just turned out to be a [waste of time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281168/#comment913381_281171), of which I am not in the habit.

Comment: FYI, the links you've included are not accessible (to lower rep users, at least)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GIFs never required special support. They work because images work.

As for YouTube, some sites (e.g. [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)) asked for YouTube embeds because both video games and home projects tend to lend themselves well to video explanations. They (at the time) provided examples of posts that would benefit from the embeds, and that was eventually implemented.

This pattern is the same for all new requested features: when there's an idea, we evaluate the pros and cons and either make them happen or not. When a community asks for a new feature (or for an existing feature to be enabled, in some cases), we ask for supporting use cases.

---

Having said that... as mentioned in the comments on your other question, you're putting the cart before the horse, so to speak. If there's a need for WebGL support... we can talk about technical issues. They may well *be* showstoppers, or delay implementation by X amount of time, but there's no point in discussing the technical aspects until there's some agreement that there's a reason to even consider them at all in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a little uncomfortable with the idea that any discussion of B *must be prevented* before a discussion of A. Since discussions are voluntary, it's not like asking B drains resources or bandwidth from meta. This is not a parliamentary system where only one speaker and one subject are allowed at any one time. It is possible someone has looked into this on their own time and may know of a show-stopper or serious hurdle. I don't understand why some are compelled to stop me from asking and finding out.

Comment: I think a key concept in your answer is that it might be best to propose or discuss at a community level first - at the 'committee level', vet it there before bringing it to the general assembly, so to speak. I think that might be a good way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh - no one is saying such discussion *must be prevented* - just that the discussion is *pointless* before the need is agreed upon. We are not in the habit of wasting time.

Comment: @Oded A quick check for the existence of known show-stoppers before trying to build a compelling argument and substantial interest that would fly here *really is* the correct order. It is a smart and agile thing to do. About the other thing, I can probably find plenty of comments and discussions within meta that are arguably both pointless and a waste of time. It's not a habit, but it's certainly not hard to find here if you look for it.